# Generate uniformly distributed random numbers between [a b] which occur with probability c

Tags: matlab, random, floating-point, numbers

I want to generate noise which is uniformly distributed and in range of [a b] and occur with probability of c and otherwise zero

I have one approach

```
x = rand(1,n);
y = zeros(1,n);
    for i = 1:n
        if x(i) > 1-c
            y(i) = rand()*(b-a)+a;
        end 
    end
```

But I am not sure whether it is correct or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "occur with probability of c uniformly"?

Comment: I don't know what you want to implement, but you could replace it with `x = rand(1,n)<c;
y = zeros(1,n);
y(x)=rand(size(y(x))).*(b-a)+a` which is much faster for large n and does the same.

Comment: `rand` already generates random numbers under a uniform distribution (a.k.a. equiprobable).  What you have there is correct, but go with Daniel's approach and do it vectorized.

Comment: @Daniel I am not sure but I think that OP wants 70 % of the values to be within this interval and uniformly distributed. I am not sure what he wants to do with the rest of the values though, so the problem might get an increased complexity when OP tells us x. Just realized that my answer is similar to your comment though. Just send an answer and then I will remove mine.

Comment: I want to generate noise which is uniformly distributed and in range of [a b] and occur with probability of c. and otherwise zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you make it to difficult for you here. The function `rand` generate uniformly distributed numbers between 1 and 0. The probability that any number in the interval [0,1] occur is always 100%. This means that a uniform distribution of `n` numbers in the interval `[a,b]` with a mean (a+b)/2 can be generated as

```
val = (b-a) * rand(n,1) + a;
```

If you want something to occur with a probability `c`, then something else need to happen `1-c` times, eg

```
val = (b-a) * rand(n,1) + a;
val(rand(n,1)>c) = 0;
```

where val is zero otherwise. This is just an example with the zeros. It is hard to give a better answer with the information given in the question.

Comment: I want to generate noise which is uniformly distributed and in range of [a b] and occur with probability of c. and otherwise zero.

Comment: @imtiyazkhan Then the vector `val` sholud be what you look for. **The variable `val` will be a vector of `n` samples, where c percent of them is different from 0 and uniformly distributed in the interval [a,b]**. So in the other words, the noise power is uniformly distributed, given a bernoulli distributed noise. If this is not the answer you are looking for you should rephrase your question.

Comment: @ patrik. Its seems that what I have done and your is same. And if it is correct then mine is also correct.

Comment: @imtiyazkhan I suppose, however you may prefer my version or [Daniels version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969679/generate-uniformly-distributed-random-numbers-between-a-b-which-occur-with-pro/28971954?noredirect=1#comment46191186_28969679) from the comment. That one is vectorized. This means it is cleaner, and maybe a little faster.